# How to add information in-between tags when creating an xml with Java

Tags: java, xml, document

I want to create an XML files that looks like this :

```
<fml-apml>
<bml>
    <speech id="s1" start="0.0" language="english" voice="openmary" type="SAPI4" text="">
        <description level="1" type="xxx">
            <reference>tmp/from-fml-apml.pho</reference>
        </description>

        <tm id="tm1"/>
             TEXT 1
        <tm id="tm2"/>
             TEXT 2
        <tm id="tm3"/>  
             TEXT 3
        <tm id="tm4"/>
             TEXT 4
        <tm id="tm5"/>  

    </speech>
</bml>
<fml>
   <some more code> 
</fml>
</fml-apml>
```

The thing is I'm using the DocumentBuilder library and I can't find a way to insert the "Text XX"  in betweens tags. Is there a way to do so or should I write the entire XML from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Document.createTextNode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createTextNode(java.lang.String)). For example

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

Element speechElem = doc.createElement("speech");
doc.appendChild(speechElem);

speechElem.appendChild(doc.createElement("tm"));
speechElem.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("TEXT 1"));
speechElem.appendChild(doc.createElement("tm"));
speechElem.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("TEXT 2"));
speechElem.appendChild(doc.createElement("tm"));
```

results in

```
<speech>
    <tm/>TEXT 1<tm/>TEXT 2<tm/>
</speech>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you don't want to include the text between the tags in any tag? that doesn't seem like a well formatted XML